# Rotating A Tile In A BufferedImage

Tags: java, tiles, bufferedimage

I have created a a bufferedImage of 6 tiles of 2 rows and 3 columns  and i want to rotate the last tile of the second row. This tile serves as a crossing for my animation.

My problems are :

How can i get access to that specifc tile alone and rotate it alone without affecting others.

I have googled for a while but no answer.

Comment: If you register yourself and login, then you can find your questions in the user profile which you can access by clicking anywhere your name appears as a link, like here: [Eddy Freeman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/334552/eddy-freeman). Your lost question is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782068/bufferedimage-help Please continue there.

Comment: Hi Eddy; this has been undeleted - discussed more on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49176/why-have-you-romoved-my-post/49178#49178

Answer (score 0):

<s>Read this [sample code](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Content-Management-System/apache-lenya-2.0/org/apache/cocoon/reading/imageop/RotateOperation.java.htm) on how to</s> rotate a WritableRaster using [AffineTransform](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) and AffineTransformOp. You should be able to figure out how to obtain a WritableRaster from a tile in a BufferedImage if you look at the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html).

Disclaimer: I haven't ever done this myself. This is purely a research based answer.

Comment: The requested document was not found on this server.

Comment: Edited to put a strike-through the text with the link. I couldn't find a suitable replacement. However, the javadoc for `AffineTransform` does talk about 90 degree rotations.